# replace a variable of another file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file I want to edit.

at the beginning, I take another file, I add for each line "\0A", I delete the end-of-line characters, and I put it in an OV variable

```
OV=$(cat certificate_file | sed  's/$/\\OH/' | tr -d '\n')   #Add \OH + delete end of 
                                                              line caracter
```

Now I want to replace the contents of the config_var1= variable in the conf file, with what is in OV

I tried to use this command:

```
sed -i -r "s:config_var1=.*:config_var1=$OV:g" config_file
```

but it doesn’t work because I have a line like this in the OV vriable :

```
8d:c8:c7:r5:m8:e1:ub:f3:09:2s:c1:5a:7a:b7:c0:cb
```

so i got this error :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2239: unknown option to `s'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` can use any character as a separator between the regex and the replacement. Choose some character that does not appear in `$OV`. For example:

```sh
sed -i -r "s#config_var1=.*#config_var1=$OV#g" config_file
```

If all of the characters are used and your script is running on Bash (non-POSIX), you can use substitution while expanding the variable and replacing the delimiter to escape it with the `${var/exp/subst}` syntax. If your delimiter is `@`, you should do it like this: `${OV/@/\\@}`. Note the double backslash to display a literal backslash.

Comment: same error because they have a # too

sed: -e expression #1, char 1534: unknown option to `s'

Comment: @lystack You should choose a character that does not appear in `$OV`.

Comment: I think all the characters are used

Comment: @lystack See my updated answer.

Comment: same... another solution... I want to replace the complete line that contains config_var1=  with the content of OV 

How can I do that?